# Adding space between 2 columns in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two pictures in a row with `img-fluid` class.
They are both of the same width and are taking all the space in the div.

I'm struggling to add space between them.

**I have tried 3 things:**

1. I've added padding-right to the left one and padding-left to the
   right one, but it looks bad on a mobile phone when they are each on
   a new line (as you would expect).
2. I've tried to add a third div between them with just a padding, but it ruins the structure.
3. And of course, I've tried to give them col-sm-5 instead of col-sm-6, but in that case the gap between them is too big.

**How can I add 5-10 pixels between them without ruining other things?**

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-0">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-0">
   <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the responsive padding classes (ie: `pr-sm-2`)...

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid px-0">
        <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-between">
            <div class="col-sm-6 pr-sm-2">
                <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/9FeTihZoPs

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I read about responsive padding classes in Bootstrap docs, but they didn't include examples of how to use it. Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row justify-content-between">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
   <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
   
  </div>
  
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
   <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
   
  </div>

       <div class="row justify-content-between">
  
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
   <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

### **Here, space between two images and adding multiple same image's below to show it's working. I don't know how much space you want between them.**

**css code**

```
<style>
  .wrapper {
    max-width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
   }
</style>
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row justify-content-between">

       <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
       <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-between">

        <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
       <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

      </div>

           <div class="row justify-content-between">

        <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/912110/pexels-photo-912110.jpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 pt-2">
       <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/white-cloud-blue-sky-sea_74190-4488.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Bharti, but in this scenario the pictures do not take all the space in the div and hence it's not practical. As you can see in my example, they should be touching borders of the wrapper div.